Hibernate statistics does not cover .save() or .deleteAll() methods from CrudRepository
I have a spring boot application, with spring data-jpa (v3.2.2) running on java 17.
I have activated generate_statistics and have configured a custom stats.factory and a custom session_factory.statement_inspector that intercept "any" SQL method being called.
I am trying to obtain some extra information about all SQL calls made by the application and their runtime, but it seems that the Statistics API does not cover insert/delete methods that are triggered by the spring pre-defined .save(), .findById() and .deleteAll() methods from CrudRepository. Can you explain why, please?
More specifically:
I have 1 entity:
@Entity
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(name="MyEntity.findByField2", query = "select e from MyEntity e where e.field2 = :someValue")
)
@Data
@ToString
@Table(name = "ent")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version = 0;

    private String field1;

    private Integer field2;
}

1 repository:
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query("select e.id from MyEntity e where e.field1 = :someValue")
    public abstract List<Long> getIdsByField1(@Param("someValue") String someValue);

    @Query(value = "select field1 from ent where field2 = :someValue", nativeQuery = true)
    public abstract List<String> getField1ByField2(@Param("someValue") Integer someValue);

    public List<MyEntity> findByField2(@Param("someValue") Integer field2);

}

A custom statement inspector:
@Slf4j
public class SqlQueryInspector implements StatementInspector {

    @Override
    public String inspect(String s) {
        log.error("QUERY: {}", s);
        return s;
    }
}

and the corresponding setting in application.yaml set:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector=org.example.hibernate.SqlQueryInspector

A custom StatisticsFactory that creates a custom StatisticsImpl:
@Slf4j
public class CustomStatisticsFactory implements StatisticsFactory {
    @Override
    public StatisticsImplementor buildStatistics(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {
        return new CustomStatisticsInitiator(sessionFactory);
    }
}

@Slf4j
public class CustomStatisticsInitiator extends StatisticsImpl {

    public CustomStatisticsInitiator(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void queryExecuted(String hql, int rows, long time) {
        log.info("########## [{}], [{}], [{}]", hql, rows, time);
        super.queryExecuted(hql, rows, time);
    }
}

with the corresponding property in application.yaml:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.stats.factory=org.example.hibernate.CustomStatisticsFactory

I call the following methods from the repo:
repo.save(myEntity);
repo.getIdsByField1("someString");
repo.getField1ByField2(1);
repo.findByField2(2);
repo.findAll();
repo.findById(1L);
repo.deleteAll();

At runtime, when requesting the statistics through Statistics API (see snippet used below), I see that I has only 4 QueryStatistics, the equivalent for findAll(), findByField2(int), getIdsByField1(String) and getField1ByField2(int). But not for save(), deleteAll() or findById. But the StatementInspector is called with all queries (but it only contains the sql, not the times). Why aren't all queries present through the Statistics API and how I can also get information about the other methods as well?
Code for obtaining Statistics:
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
String[] queries = stats.getQueries();
for (String query : queries) {
    QueryStatistics queryStats = stats.getQueryStatistics(query);
    // do something
}


have you try to add this logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE in your application.property to see what's happening?
